# Can I use Microsoft.com account to log into OpenSSH server on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, openssh

I am trying to set up my Windows 10 (Home edition build 19042.546) desktop computer with OpenSSH server so I can use VSCode Remote from a laptop. I have OpenSSH server installed and I can log in to it remotely if I create a local user on the machine so I know that the server itself works. But back when I bought it and set up the machine initially I went the "log in with your Microsoft account" route. I am unclear how to log into that account from ssh.

For the test commands below I am running from a local PowerShell, but the results are the same from a separate machine.

I have tried `ssh myname@my-domain.com@localhost` and it does ask me for a password but then gives me `Permission denied, please try again` twice and then `Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)`.

I ran `Get-LocalUser -Name Admin | select *` to confirm that Admin is indeed the user associated to my Microsoft Account. I tried logging in with `ssh Admin@localhost` and got the same result as the above login attempt.

I looked at the sshd_config (still in it's default state) but I am a bit at a loss of what to try there given the vast number of options. Is it even possible to use a MicrosoftAccount user for this? I am hoping to avoid using another account to run under but will if I have to.

Cheers

Comment: Personally, I always set up a local account *first* and then convert it to a Windows account.  This way the local account user id can still be used for things like this.  It also is "tidier" in my opinion when your files are in something like `C:\Users\username` rather than letting Windows create the user id based on an email address or long name.

Answer (score 3):

I am setting up an SSH server on my windows machine that is using my live account. I have no local accounts configured. I came across this [post](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-win10-ssh-service.html) that goes into some good detail. Tucked away in that post under "Logging into the SSH Server" the author talks about how you can login using your windows account or a local account.
Essentially, open PowerShell and type:

```
whoami
```

and the response you get should be the username. Mine came out to something like below for example:

```
laptop-yadda-yadda\longbe
```

The portion that is significant is the `longbe` part. My real username is `LongBeachHXC` but to get logged in using SSH I need to use the `longbe` like so:

```
ssh longbe@laptop-ip-or-dns-address
```